Square roots and prime numbers
Definitions:
Here I present a novel conjecture using basic mathematical tools like the sum of the divisors of an integer $n$ called $\sigma(n)$, the sum of the squares of the positive divisors of $n$ called $\sigma_2(n)$ I also use the prime-counting function which is the function counting the number of prime numbers less than or equal to some real number $n$. The prime-counting function is called $\pi(n)$
Conjecture:
We introduce the following expression called $A$:
$$A = \sigma_2(\pi(n) − \sigma(n + 2))$$
We focus on numbers ends with $2$. I calculate $A − 1$ and so the new number ends with $1$. Then I calculate the square root of this number ends with $1$. When the number is an integer, it is always prime.
Example:
Let $n = 100547$, we have $A = \sigma_2(9639 − \sigma(100549)) = 8264809922$
We have $A − 1 = 8264809921$ and we calculate the square root of 8264809921 and we have $\sqrt{A−1} = \sqrt{8264809921} = 90911$ and 90911 is prime.
Questions

Is this conjecture interesting?
Is it possible to prove this conjecture or to find counter-example?

Generalization of the conjecture
If $\sqrt{A-1}$ is an integer so $\sqrt{A-1}$ is always prime.
The generalization of the conjecture is false (see the counter-example below).
Now, we focus on the first conjecture with numbers ending with $2$.

The conjecture looks very ad hoc to me, so I am pretty certain that it is false. How many positive examples did you find up to $n=2000000$?

@GH from MO: I just edited my post to show the C++ program I used: https://www.onlinegdb.com/3yNzqH_ag This code could answer to your question.

Why do you expect that I (or anyone here) know how to run a C++ program? We are mathematicians, not programmers. It's your program, so please use it to answer my question.

I didn't code the proportion of real numbers $n$ satisfying the rule (i.e numbers end with 2). Sorry, it's difficult for me, I am a noob in programmation, I just achieved a minimal code (i.e to know if there is a counter-example in the range from $n=1$ to $n=2000000$).

I think what you observe is this. If $m$ is prime, then $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square, namely $m^2$. If $m$ is composite, then $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is rarely a square, and it happens even more rarely that such an $m$ is of the form $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$.

Ok, I see. Is it a real proof or just an observation? Because with $n=100547$ I obtain a new prime number which is $90911$. The formula is not simply $\sigma_2(n)-1=n^2$ and $\sqrt{n^2}=n$ This is more complex. For example with $n=100547$ we obtain $\sigma_2(\pi(100547)-\sigma(100549)=8264809922$ With $\sqrt{A-1}$ we obtain $90911$ (see above). With your formula we have with $n=27$ : $\sigma(29)-\pi(27)=30-9=21$ However with my formula we find another number for $n=27$ : $\sigma_2(\sigma(29)-\pi(27))=500$, which is different from 21. So, the two formulas are not equivalent.

Minor comment, your code is in Python, not C++

I abbreviated your $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$ as $m$. For $n=100547$ we have $m=90911$, which is a prime, so it happens to be the same as $\sqrt{\sigma_2(m)-1}$. You are generating a prime $m$ from itself. Finding a counterexample to your conjecture will be difficult, simply because it is difficult to find a composite $m$ for which $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square.

@GH from MO: perhaps we can prove this formula? I just edited the program, it is true 74408 times for numbers from $n=1$ to $n=2,000,000$

Prove which formula? There surely exist composite $m$'s for which $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square, but you will not find it by a linear search, because such $m$'s are so rare. Once you find such an $m$ (e.g. with 1000 digits), you can ask if this $m$ is of the form $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$.

My point is that all the positive examples (in the given range), where you end up with a prime, are such that $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$ is itself a prime, the same prime. For example, in the case of $n=100547$, the final prime $90911$, which is just $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$. Your question is not really about $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$, but about the integers $m$ for which $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square number. Most of these $m$'s are primes: it is virtually impossible to find a composite $m$ with this property as such $m$'s are so rare.

@GH from MO: ok I see. But perhaps we can verify that my formula doesn't contain a counter-example. And a proof is necessary in this case. Is it really difficult to prove this?

I cannot prove that there is a counterexample, but it is very likely that there are counterexamples. I tried to explain this, but apparently you are not following. A simpler and nicer variant of your conjecture is this: if $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square number, then $m$ is a prime number. Again, this is surely false, but finding a counterexample will be tricky. For example, if $m$ is a product of two prime numbers, then it is immediate that $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is not a square number. I finish the discussion here!

A small correction to my last comment. Actually $m=6$ is a product of two primes for which $\sigma_2(m)-1=49$ is a square number. It can be shown that there is no other $m$ which is the product of two primes for which $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square number.

@GHfromMO apparently $40$  also satisfies your version, next $136$

so far: 6 =  2 3 ///
40 =  2^3 5    ///
136 =  2^3 17  ///
2696 =  2^3 337 ///
3352 =  2^3 419 ///
46976 =  2^7 367 ///
223736 =  2^3 27967 ///

@WillJagy Yes, I was sloppy when I wrote that comment. The set of non-prime $m$'s up to $10^7$ for which $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square equals ${1,6,40,136,2696,3352,46976,223736,5509736}$. Probably there are infinitely many such $m$'s even when you add the condition that $\sigma_2(m)\equiv 2\pmod{10}$ and $m$ lies in the range of $\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$. And such an $n$ would falsify the OP's conjecture. Probably the OP's conjecture is the result of an evolution where artificial conditions were gradually added to make the counterexamples disappear.

@WillJagy I just noticed that this sequence is available at OEIS, the next term being $m=1915798072$: https://oeis.org/A318169

This question looks remarkably similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461849/.

Just for record - $46976$ is $\sigma(31882)-\pi(31880)$, and $\sigma_2(46976)-1=(3^37^241)^2$

@მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Good to know. Let us note that this is not a counterexample to the OP's conjecture, because $(3^37^241)^2$ does not end with $1$.

Right. This is one of the entries from A318169, they all have form $m=2^{2k-1}p$ for an odd prime $p$, and as you showed $\sigma_2(2^{2k-1})$ is divisible by $5$, while $\sigma_2(p)$ is even, so all $\sigma_2(m)-1$ there end with $9$.

@GHfromMO As far as I see, according to Conjecture, $m$ should be equal to $\pi(n)-\sigma(n+2)$ instead of
$\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$.

@AlexRavsky It does not matter as $\sigma_2(m)=\sigma_2(-m)$. In fact, usually, $\sigma_2$ is not even defined for negative integers, while $\pi(n)-\sigma(n+2)$ is always negative.

Can someone please tell me what "We focus on numbers ends with 2" means mathematically?

@DanielAsimov "ends with $2$" means "congruent to $2$ modulo $10$".

I am now inclined to believe that the OP's conjecture is true, and I present some ideas to support this. If $n$ is a counterexample, then $m:=\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$ is a composite number such that $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square number ending in $1$. The goal would be to prove that there is no such $m$ (regardless of $n$).
Let us focus on the composite numbers $m$ such that $\sigma_2(m)-1$ is a square number. These numbers are listed at OEIS, and it seems that they are all even. Let us assume this, and let $k>0$ be the exponent of $2$ in $m$. I claim that $k$ is odd. To see this, observe that every divisor of $\sigma_2(2^k)$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, because it is an odd number dividing $\sigma_2(m)$, which is a square number plus $1$. However, if $k$ is even, then
$$\sigma_2(2^k)=\frac{4^{k+1}-1}{3}=\frac{(2^{k+1}+1)(2^{k+1}-1)}{3}$$
is divisible by $2^{k+1}-1$, which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. So $k$ is odd (under the standing assumption that $m$ is even). But this implies that $\sigma_2(2^k)$ is divisible by $5$, because in the previous display $4^{k+1}=16^{(k+1)/2}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $5$. Hence $\sigma_2(m)$ is divisible by $5$, and therefore $\sigma_2(m)-1$ does not end in $1$.
To summarize, the OP's conjecture follows from the more natural conjecture that the linked OEIS sequence consists of even numbers.

Thank you for your answer. Is it a proof?

@Sulfura It is not a complete proof. What I show is that as long as $m=\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$ is even, your conjecture is true. In addition, it is plausible that the remaining case, i.e. when $m=\sigma(n+2)-\pi(n)$ is odd, produces no counterexample.

I'm not so sure about absence of odd terms in OEIS A318169. Here is a near-miss: were $p:=411706627786612628571$ a prime, $11^4\cdot p$ would be such a term as $\sigma_2(11^4)(1+p^2)-1$ is a square.

@MaxAlekseyev Yes, it is hard to make a guess. The question has a similar flavor (at least to me) as the existence of odd perfect numbers. I agree that a more extensive search is necessary here (perhaps a clever search, not a bruce force search). Please keep us updated!

This conjecture is part of the larger conjecture:
$A = \sigma_2(n) \ \ \text{ where } \ \ 1 <= n < \infty$
with the same other conditions:
If $ \ A \ $ has a last digit of $ \ 2 \ $, and if $\sqrt{A - 1}$ is an integer, then $\sqrt{A - 1} $ is also a prime number.

Yes, I emphasized this in my response: "The goal would be to prove that there is no such $m$ (regardless of $n$)."

It was proven with a simple code that there is no counterexample for$ \ \ n<100e6  \ \ $(just adjust the Python code in the main post).

My response and the linked OEIS page make it clear that there is no counterexample up to $2\cdot 10^{12}$. Also, it suffices to check odd numbers only (cf. my response).

GH from MO's answer suggests to study (odd) composite numbers $m$ such that $\sigma_2(m)−1$ is a square. Therefore $\sigma_2(m)$ is not divisible by $4$ and has no (prime) divisors equal $3$ modulo $4$. Let $m=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ be the prime decomposition of $m$. Then
$$\sigma_2(m)=(1+p_1^2+\dots+p_1^{2a_1})\dots (1+p_k^2+\dots+p_k^{2a_k})=$$ $$\frac{p_1^{2a_1+2}-1}{p_1^2-1}\cdots \frac{p_k^{2a_k+2}-1}{p_k^2-1}.$$
In particular, if $m$ is odd then no $a_i$ equals $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$ and at most one $a_i$ is odd (and in this case it equals $1$ modulo $8$). Moreover, for each natural $i\le k$ the greatest common divisor of $p_i^2-1$ and $a_i+1$ has no divisors $q$ equal $3$ modulo $4$, because otherwise $1+p_i^2+\dots+p_i^{2a_i}$ divides $q$.
Moreover, suppose that $\sigma_2(m)\equiv 2\pmod {10}$, as required. Then exactly one $a_i$, say, $a_1$ equals $1$ modulo $8$ and each other $a_i$ is divisible by $4$.
I am trying to advance this study farther.

My conjecture is false.
With $n=31880$ we have $A=\sigma_2(|\pi(31880)-\sigma(31882)|)=\sigma_2(|3424-50400|)=\sigma_2(46976)=2942303050$
We have $A-1=2942303049$ and $\sqrt{2942303049}=54243$
Here we have $\sqrt{A-1}=54243$ that is an integer but $54243$ is not prime ($54243=3^3*7^2*41$)

Shouldn't the integer $A$ end with a $2$?

No because the conjecture has been generalized for all natural numbers (see my post) and we have this counter-example.

This example was already mentioned by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე on 7 Aug 2024 at 4:38. It is in a comment below the original post. And I commented shortly after that "Good to know. Let us note that this is not a counterexample to the OP's conjecture, because $(3^37^241)^2$ does not end with $1$."

Now we try to prove the first conjecture (numbers ends with 2).

Here it is a program for searching counter-examples. There is no counter-examples up to n=1 000 000 000
The program: https://textup.fr/813621ac
We focus on numbers ending with 2.

My response and the linked OEIS page make it clear that there is no counterexample up to $2\cdot 10^{12}$. Also, it suffices to check odd numbers only (cf. my response).
